# Separating users database into two different collections

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I want to build a project that will contain different type of users such us Admins & Employees.

Is it possible to make it done through `accounts-password` and `accounts-ui` by separating `Meteor.users` collection?

Comment: There is a sometimes-used pattern where a completely different admin app is written, hosted on a different url but sharing the same mongoDB database, including the users collection. The admin app might have additional access restrictions (such as being limited to specific IP addresses etc..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, users is the heart of the authentication system.

I would recommend using the package alanning:roles to provide different levels of privilege.

Read more here
https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles

There is a package to help administer these here https://github.com/hharnisc/meteor-accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into it :)