# How to verify user credentials when logging in?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have created a dummy collection with one username and password for testing purposes. I want to check if I can successfully login if the information were right.

I am storing the user input in sessions as below:

```
Template.contactus.events({
      'submit #hr-login': function (e, t) {

        e.preventDefault();

        Session.set('username', t.find('#username').value);
        Session.set('password', t.find('#password').value);

        Router.go('/message');

      }
});
```

I tried the following code:

```
     var check = hr.findOne({username: Session.get('username'), pass: Session.get('password')});
if(check){
    Router.go('/message');
}
```

Unfortunately, it didn't solve it for me.

How do I check if the user input are correct and matches the username and password in the collection?

**UPDATE**

I am aware of `accounts-ui` and `accounts-password` packages, but due to my project requirements I can't use them

Comment: Not sure if I understand you. Are you trying to building your own user account system without using the one comes with Meteor?

Comment: @Khang, I want to create a system where there will be more than a single collection to store user accounts. For example, collection will store the accounts of admins, another collection will store the accounts of the employees and so on. Meteor accounts package limited to one collection if am not mistaken. I am not sure if there exists certain packages that will help me with my specifications

Comment: This is no ordinary task, you would have to modify Meteor's core packages code to store users' documents in different collections and still let them login. If you really have to do that, start with this package: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/accounts-base.

Comment: I would like to point out that it is utterly nonsense to follow this approach from the MongoDB side alone. Even when employees and admin accounts had literally nothing in common aside from the existence of the `_id` field, you still could store them in the same collection.

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg, Exactly what I wanted to hear, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `accounts-password`, instead of making different collection for the admins and employees for this there is a very helpful package `alanning:roles` you add this package by `meteor add alanning:roles`

Go to this github link for the documentation and usage.
https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

Comment: just one question to make sure I don't face problems in future. I want to add another layer which will be for the CEO. The CEO will have a feature to add users for the system as admins or employees. Can I link the added user (Admin/Employee) to its correct roles? without having to play around with the code? in future?

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi , Yes you can add further roles to the user and specify permissions , It is stated in the doc ,  even I had a scenario in my application where admin can add users but simple employees cannot , my purpose was solved using 'alannig:roles' package.

Comment: good to hear that, now i feel comfortable using it :), one last question if I may. I want my system to only allow logins without registrations, can i make it done through meteor accounts package?

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi, So you want the user to login without even registrations ?

Comment: Exactly, I want to add one user "manually" from Mongo shell, that user will be responsible for adding the rest of the users. Therefore, I need to take out the registration, is it possible to do so? based on your experience. :)

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi, This is extreme coincidence , even this I have implemented in my project , what I did , I created an admin account at the server startup if it already does not exists and then logged in as admin and created other accounts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128787/discussion-between-piyush-kumar-and-behrouz-riahi).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you are aware of the Meteor accounts package - it would be much easier for you to use that. It also provides Facebook/Google login and many others, all pretty much out of the box.

https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html

There are packages that you can install to do most of the work for you

Comment: I am aware of that package, but I have to create my own login due to my project requirements.

Comment: You are thinking about a long road here. Have a look at this answer (similar to your problem) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731234/separating-users-database-into-two-different-collections/40732229#40732229